# Cookie not saving between pages

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am setting a cookie on one page with below code

```
setcookie(codeDone,true);
```

This works but then I reset it to false on another page

```
setcookie(codeDone,false);
```

But then, when I go back to the first page, before the part that sets it to true I have

```
if($_COOKIE['codeDone'] == true){
$cookie = $_COOKIE['codeDone'];
$done = false;
echo"cookie set to $cookie";
}
setcookie(codeDone,true);
```

For some reason the ocokie is set to true because the contents of this if are always executed

Why is the cookie returning true (1) if in the previous page i set it to false?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are only string-values.

The code below is an example for your case to handle string as boolean:

```
ob_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE['codeDone'])) {

    //this is your magic
    $result = filter_var($_COOKIE['codeDone'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);

    if ($result === true) {
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['codeDone'];
        $done = false;
        echo "Current Cookie Status: ".$_COOKIE['codeDone'];
    }
}
setcookie('codeDone', 'true');

ob_end_flush();
```

BTW: You cannot modify the header (setcookie) after executed echo. this is the reason why i use the output buffer (ob_start/ob_end_flush)